# R Mapply to unzip - file path changes

Tags: r, loops, unzip, mapply

I have a list of input filepaths titled 'list' and a list of output filepaths titled 'out'. These look like:

```
   Input:
    \\data\New Jersey\2020-10-27\Results.zip
    \\data\Alabama\2020-10-27\Results.zip

   Output:
   \\data\New Jersey\2020-10-27
   \\data\Alabama\2020-10-27
```

I would like to loop through the 'Input' list and unzip the file to the 'Output' list folder.

I have tried the following two approaches:

```
  for(i in 1:length(list)) {unzip(zipfile = list[i], exdir = out[i])}
  mapply(unzip, zipfile = list, exdir = out)
```

When I use the for loop I receive an error saying 'invalid path argument'.  When I use the mapply function, R changes the backslashes to forward slashes and says there is no file or directory.  Why is mapply trying to change backslashes to forward slashes?

For example, it tries to open the file: \date/New Jersey/2020-10-27/Results.zip

Thanks!

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Even if you are on a Windows system, where backslashes are used in file paths, you need to use forward slashes in file paths in R. Take a look at this: https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/impatient-r/more-r-startup/more-r-startup-windows/#pathname

Comment: I am using Windows - I have tried forward slashes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What does vapply(Input, file.exists, logical(1)) return? I suspect there's a problem with the partial path (i.e. not having something like C:/...)